# dart child process doesn't have access to terminal

Tags: dart, terminal, command-line-interface

I have a dart process which spawns a child dart process.

The parent dart process has access to the terminal which I can check via the call:

```
stdin.hasTerminal
```

The child dart process however returns false when I call stdin.hasTerminal.

The parent process wires each of stdin/stdout/stderr to the child process which is all I thought would be required for the child to have access to the terminal.

Here is the method I use to spawn the child dart process:

parent.dart

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:cli';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('parent hasTerminal=${stdin.hasTerminal}');
  // Execute the script
  final process = waitFor<Process>(Process.start('dart', ['child.dart']));

  // Pipe std out and in
  final StreamSubscription stderrSub =
      process.stderr.listen((List<int> d) => stderr.add(d));
  final StreamSubscription stdoutSub =
      process.stdout.listen((List<int> d) => stdout.add(d));
  final StreamSubscription stdinSub =
      stdin.listen((List<int> d) => process.stdin.add(d));

  final exitCode = waitFor<int>(process.exitCode);

  final futures = <Future<void>>[];

  futures.add(stderrSub.cancel());
  futures.add(stdoutSub.cancel());
  futures.add(stdinSub.cancel());

  waitFor<void>(Future.wait(futures));

  exit(exitCode);
}
```

And this is the child process I spawn:

child.dart

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('child: has terminal: ${stdin.hasTerminal}');
}
```

You can run the example by placing both files in the same directory and running:

dart parent.dart

When I run the app I get:

```dart
dart parent.dart 
parent hasTerminal=true
child: has terminal: false
```

I did wonder if using 'dart child.dart' to start the child process might be part of the problem.

So I compiled the child.dart script using dart2native and then changed the parent script to directly call the new executable 'child'.

The results were however the same. Even when I spawned the exe directly child does not have access to the terminal.

I should note that if I run the child exe or run `dart child.dart` from the cli then the child script has access to the terminal.

Comment: I've just ran a test where I had the parent process call a bash script. And once again I see the same results. If I run the bash script directly it has terminal access. If I run the bash script via the above parent.dart then it doesn't have terminal access. So it definitely looks like a problem with how dart is spawning and connecting to a child process.

Answer (score 3):

So this turned out to be easier than expected.

The following script launches `vi` padding `fred.text` as the name of the file to edit.

The code then waits for `vi` to finish.

```dart
import 'dart:cli';
import 'dart:io';

void main()
{
  // Execute the script
    final process = waitFor<Process>(Process.start('vi', ['fred.text'],
        mode: ProcessStartMode.inheritStdio));

    final exitCode = waitFor<int>(process.exitCode);
}
```

The Process.start method has a mode 'inheritStdio'. When you set this dart attaches the child process directly to the terminal.

The first call to waitFor causes the script to wait for 'vi' to start and the second waitFor causes the script to wait for 'vi' to end.

In this scenario you can't intercept the io moving between the child and the terminal but  I can't think of any scenarios where this would be useful.

Comment: waitFor is going to be removed in Dart 3.4. https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.3/dart-cli/waitFor.html

Comment: @robotoaster I am aware. I'm working on dcli 4.x which removes the dependency.